# For Loop Batch Copy Raster TIFF to BMP in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, batch, raster-conversion

I need to convert TIFFs to BMPs using CopyRaster from ascii to raster output TIFFs. I am not sure how to define the "outRaster" so that it will convert the rasters to BMP. I'm guessing that the line of code which I denote below needs additional consideration.

```
import os,arcpy,glob

rasterpath = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout"
outFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowrast"
rasterList = glob.glob(rasterpath + "/*.tif")

for rasterFile in rasterList:
    outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, rasterFile + "bmp") #THIS LINE??
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(rasterFile,outRaster,"#","-3.402823e    +038","NONE","NONE","8_BIT_UNSIGNED","ScalePixelValue","NONE")
```

***NOTE - The code below works to convert to jpg or bmp although I would guess some syntax is missing.

```
import os,arcpy,glob

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowtest2"
outFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowtest3"

for rasterFile in arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif"):

    oName, oExt = os.path.splitext(rasterFile + ".jpg")
    outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, oName + ".jpg") 
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(rasterFile,outRaster,"#","#","-9999","NONE","NONE","8_BIT_UNSIGNED","NONE","NONE")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, rasterFile + "bmp") #THIS LINE??
```

should be

```
outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, rasterFile + ".bmp") #THIS LINE??
```

instead of using glob perhaps use the inbuilt [arcpy.ListRasters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000003w000000):

```
rasterpath = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout"
outFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowrast"
arcpy.env.workspace = rasterpath 
for rasterFile in arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif"):
    oName, oExt = os.path.splitext(rasterFile)
    outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, oName+ ".bmp") # take off .tif and replace with .bmp
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(rasterFile,outRaster,"#","-3.402823e    +038","NONE","NONE","8_BIT_UNSIGNED","ScalePixelValue","NONE")
```

[Copy Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000) only needs you to set the file extension correctly for the file formats that it will do

Comment: I have a question about defining the in/out folders-- your code specifies the workspace as my original out folder which is empty, and 'outFolder' is not defined. If I would like to have separate in and out folders, how would I set the workspace/s?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I've just come back from holiday. Yes, you're right, the arcpy.env.workspace is the folder (or geodatabase) that has the rasters to be processed, sorry I must have copy-pasted the wrong path as I slowly degenerated into holiday mode. Normally I would use sys.argv[n] or arcpy.GetParameterAsText(n) to set in and out and run the tool from batch file, command prompt or ArcCatalog toolbox. I'll fix up that path to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the direction Michael, I will try post what code I've settled on as an edit to my original post.